# How to enable already subscribed users subscribe again to the Mailchimp/Aweber/GetResponse list

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, getresponse, aweber, auto-responder

I'm creating website in WordPress. Idea is to show users sign up email subscribe form in welcome page and when user subscribes they redirects to home page, but user can't go to the home page second time because he/she already subscribed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot speak for GetResponse or MailChimp, but AWeber automatically prevents people from signing up to your list a second time. If you'd like, you can set a custom already subscribed page from within a sign up form created with our generator. You can find directions for that here:

https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/204027726-How-Do-I-Set-an-Already-Subscribed-Page-

If you're using our API to add subscribers from your site, we will give back a 400 response with the message "Subscriber already subscribed." should you try to add someone that's already on your list. You could catch that exception and direct the user to your already subscribed page or to your homepage.

We do not monitor StackOverflow on a daily basis, so if you have further questions regarding our API, please reach out to us at api@aweber.com for more assistance, as that inbox is monitored daily. For general account inquiries you can contact help@aweber.com to reach our Customer Solutions team.

Kaitlyn C.